# mac docker volume mount using osxfs not working

Tags: macos, docker, mount

Docker Desktop for Mac started using `osxfs` for supporting volume mounting on MacOS. According to [their page](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces), a command like this should mount the `~/Desktop` directory to the docker container:

```
docker run -it -v ~/Desktop:/Desktop r-base bash
```

Although I do see a `Desktop` directory as expected, its contents are empty:

```
root@80cb534e4eeb:/# ls
bin  boot  Desktop  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@80cb534e4eeb:/# ls Desktop/
root@80cb534e4eeb:/# exit
exit
```

while there are definitely files in the `Desktop` directory locally

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ ls Desktop/
Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 10.34.58.png      Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 22.26.10.png      Screen Shot 2019-03-27 at 07.34.55.png
Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 10.35.59.png      Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 22.26.11.png      Screen Shot 2019-03-28 at 15.14.48.png
Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 22.26.08.png      Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 22.47.32.png      Screen Shot 2019-04-05 at 09.26.12.png
Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 22.26.10 1.png    Screen Shot 2019-03-27 at 07.34.33.png
```

The `/Users` directory should be accessible according to the Preferences window. Seems like something is wrong with the docker configuration, but I haven't found any similar issues reported yet. Most issues related to `osxfs` are about IO performance. Any ideas on how to further solve/investigate this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you try mount the root of the vm running docker as a volume and see if you can access the Desktop folder that way. Something like `docker run --rm -v /:/vm_root --entrypoint=sh alpine -c 'ls -l /vm_root/Users/user/Desktop'`

Comment: Tried, no files visible. Also tried to access the user directory `ls -l /vm_root/Users/user` in the same way, I see that the only folders there are the folders that I have already tried to mount (even one non-existing locally). Seems like the `Users` directory of the VM does not correspond to the one of the local file system.

Comment: Ok that is strange. Maybe try to do factory reset of docker for mac? feels like a docker for mac bug somewhere? does any of the paths you configure in the preferences work?

Comment: This did it. Thanks! It's not clear what could have caused this, I never got it to work after the first install of Docker.

Comment: Ok good! Should i write a proper answer even when we dont know the resason?

Comment: Yes, good for me

Comment: Ok with the answer i wrote? more to add?

Comment: FWIW: I experienced a similar problem which was worked around by restarting the docker instance. According to docker inspect all the expected mounts were performed but inside the container the directories at the mountpoints were all empty. Restarting docker worked for me:

```Docker Desktop 4.19.0 (106363)```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker factory reset in the preferences fixed the issue but the root cause is still unknown. One way of troubleshoot this kind of issues is to volume mount the root of the linux VM used by Docker for mac and poke around. This can be done with:

```sh
docker run --rm -v /:/vm_root --entrypoint=sh alpine -c 'ls -l /vm_root/<path in macOS>'
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `<path in macOS>`?

Comment: Sure! It's a bit confusing. The paths shared with docker from the macOS host (the ones you see in Preferences/Files shared) are mounted from macOS into the linux VM running the docker daemon at the same paths as in macOS.   In my example i show how to get access to the vm root filesystem to poke around by running a container that volume mounts it. The problem is that docker does not allow for good reasons to do `-v /:/` so we have to mount it some where in the container so i named it `/vm_root`. Try `docker run --rm -ti -v /:/vm_root --entrypoint=sh alpine` to get a shell. Hope that helps.

Comment: So by `<path in macOS>` i mean some path in macOS like `/Users/...` etc

Answer (score 3):

Someone struggling with similar issue in recent Docker releases on Mac, this helped in my case.
I am using
Docker version: 20.10.10
Docker Desktop: 4.2.0

In Preferences > General there is an option "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing" which is by default checked. Uncheck that option Apply and restart.

After this for me -v option started working normally and I am able to easily share file between my Mac OS host and Docker container.

Comment: awesome, thank you! worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to write comments. @dkoder 's answer is not working for Docker version: 20.10.17 Docker Desktop: 4.12.0

If you uncheck the "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing" option and click on "Apply and restart" that option will be checked again and nothing is fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).