# Docker compose file sharing MacOS Catalina - volumes are not known to Docker

Tags: ruby, wordpress, bash, docker

I have been handed a project which uses dockerized wordpress instances which I wish to develop using docker locally (right now its just being used for deployment while edits happen locally).

Here is what is happening when I run docker-compose up.

```
Nicholas-MacBook-Pro:docker nicholasabrams$ docker-compose up 
WARNING: The WORDPRESS_HOST_VOLUME_LOCATION variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Removing redacted_wordpress_1
Redacted_db_1 is up-to-date
Recreating 41aeb49bc451_redacted_wordpress_1 ... 
Recreating 41aeb49bc451_redacted_wordpress_1 ... error

ERROR: for 41aeb49bc451_redacted_wordpress_1  Cannot start service wordpress: Mounts denied: 
The paths /redacted.com/wp-content and /readacted.com/brochure
are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.

ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: Mounts denied: 
The paths /[uri].com/wp-content and /[uri].com/[project-name]
are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
```

`
I have tried to add the two directories to the docker shared resources however the same error occurs. I could really use some help on this one as docker-compose is new to me and docker itself is not something I am an expert with. Thank you!

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Did I miss something?

Comment: while i didn't *downvote*, i suggested to *close* this question, as it this is not (directly) related to programming. see [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would rather have pointed to [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackechange.com), but I would not downvote anyway as being overly strict on the "programming" aspect does not seem helpful to me and, luckily, is not enforced in the strict way it used to be anymore.
If someone already found a "correct" question or answer, please post a link here.

Comment: Maybe a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667800/mac-docker-volume-mount-using-osxfs-not-working