# Host dir mounted but files are not visible from Docker container

Tags: docker

I want to mount current host dir to /var/www in container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0.0-fpm-alpine3.12
WORKDIR /var/www    
CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:80", "-t", "/var/www"]
```

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -d -v $(pwd):/var/www -p 80:80 test
```

docker inspect shows that it's mounted:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/library/webserver/documents/test",
                "Destination": "/var/www",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

/library/webserver/documents/test is between shared dir's in Docker Desktop preferences, but host files are not visible from container and vice versa. Why it's not working? Thanks

Comment: Maybe docker process don't have rights to /library/... Try `docker run --privileged=true -d -v $(pwd):/var/www -p 80:80 test` but it not for production.

Comment: nope, the same:/

Comment: You try to run php build-in server based on alpine image. I don't known it is correct or no. Maybe try other base.

Comment: I checkd alpine based for build-in server. It is correct. Inspect /var/www inside of container `docker exec -it container_name ash `

Comment: it's not an issue, mounting doesn't work with other images too..

Comment: what operating system? I think $pwd works only in linux and mac.

Comment: also see answer on post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10)

Comment: os is mac, so $pwd should work

Comment: Last chance [osxfs in dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667800/mac-docker-volume-mount-using-osxfs-not-working)

Comment: mounting works with docker compose